# First time making cider, will it work well

Tags: cider, first-time-brewer

I decided to try experiment after reading a little about making cider. I used a 1/2 gallon of cider, made sure there were no preservatives. Warmed it in a pot with about a cup of brown sugar and a full pack of yeast (just cheap stuff I had left from Baking). Put it in a gallon jug and made an airlock with rubber tubing and a plastic cup of water. Everything is air tight and it has been bubbling for 3 days. I know it has a few weeks left. My question is 
1. Will it be drinkable?
2. would this be considered Wine?
3. any red flags I should watch for?

Comment: You say you started with 1/2 gallon of cider - do you really mean that? I imagine you started with apple juice.

Comment: You might want to break out the "would this be considered Wine" into another question, as it isn't entirely related to the others.

Answer (score 2):

1. Unless it's infected, definitely drinkable.
2. More under the hard cider category. I guess you could say it's an apple wine, but like barely wines they are usually above 10% ABV.
3. You normally shouldn't see any weird looking crusts or floating material depending on the yeast you used. I would swirl the cider around everyday to help keep the yeast in suspension, and attenuate (create more alcohol) as much as that yeast can.

Further I would let it ferment for a full month, even if it's not bubbling. This allows the yeast to get rid of off flavors and then settle out. After the month, throw it in the fridge for a day and then siphon it out into another clean & sanitized 1/2 gal jug. Or if you want it carbonated put a half teaspoon of table sugar into a clean & sanitized growler and let it sit at room temperature for a week.

Answer (score 0):

1. Likely..you'll just have to wait and see
2. I suppose it could be
3. Possibly infection....did you sanitize everything that touched it?

Comment: Sanitized no, but made sure everthing was clean.

Comment: @DanG Sanitized and clean are not the same thing. You may get infection just wait and see how it turns out.

Comment: thanks :) How would you tell there is a infection?